# How to get only visible markers?

Tags: here-api

Is possible to get only the visible markers? Is there any function for this?

This is the function where I have the bounds:

```
hereMap.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', (evt) => {
        var bounds = hereMap.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds;

}, false);
```

Comment: It is currently unclear what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please to know what visible marker actually implies ? however if you want to limit the visibility of markers, GeoCoordinates can be specified for a bounding box and passed in mapview, that can limit the visibility of map in the view. Also you can then set the visibility of inside markers to true.